# How to Make a List Box a Drop-Down Like a Combo Box in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

in access 2007 How to Make a List Box a Drop-Down Like a Combo Box without changing it to combo box type because it has multi select property and i need to save some space on my form is that possible ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if there is enough space under ListBox try to format->bring to front and assign events

```
Private Sub MutantListbox_GotFocus()

    MutantListbox.Height = MutantListbox.Height * 10 ' it waz 1 line become 10

End Sub 

Private Sub MutantListbox_LostFocus() 

    MutantListbox.Height = MutantListbox.Height / 10 ' it waz 10 line become 1

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you , i dont have enough reputation to vote your answer , good work